# How to get html source auth after login

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

Hello I am wondering what function I can use in my script to return a confirmation that the login worked.

I am using Selenium but I am using it in headless mode. So I want an output of the auth that says the login has worked etc.

```
class loginlol:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input").click()
        username.send_keys(self.username)
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input").click()
        password.send_keys(self.password)
        password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        sleep(1)
```

what could I use to print the updated html that the login was a success? get attribute?

I tried to confirm it through find element. but Xpath doesnt work

```
        self.driver.findElement("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div[1]/div/p")
        if self.driver.findElement is True:
                print("login confirmed")
```

let me know what to do thanks :D

Comment: You can check credentials. If they are invalid you didn't.

Comment: @AlexDotis I am trying to do it by using driver.findElement, and then go to credentials in html and do i copy it as an xpath or outtter html?

Comment: If you give wrong credentials then this ```self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('eiCW-').text``` will show you a message. After that, do what you have to do

Comment: @AlexDotis I did that, but an still getting no print, or return of anything :( sad face

Comment: other than the findElements needs to be by xpath.

Comment: //*[@id="react-root"] you can use this to check for the instagram icon on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If login is Successful then check for your user name in the `page_source`*

*Example*

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def login(self):
        self.chrome_browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")

        time.sleep(2)

        email_input = self.chrome_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("form input")[0]
        password_input = self.chrome_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("form input")[1]

        email_input.send_keys(self.email)
        password_input.send_keys(self.password)
        password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        time.sleep(2)

        if "my user name" in self.chrome_browser.page_source:
            print("login confirmed")
        else:
            print("login Not confirmed")


my_bot = InstagramBot('0m3r@Email.com', 'password')
my_bot.login()
```